# What was the deeper meaning of Hermione wanting the cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

In Deathly Hallows:

> “I think you’re
>   right,” she told him. “It’s just a morality tale, it’s obvious which gift
>   is best, which one you’d choose —”
>   The three of them spoke at the same time; Hermione said, “the
>   Cloak,” Ron said, “the wand,” and Harry said, “the stone.”

It's obvious why Harry picked the Stone: The whole theme of the story is his overcoming death. And it's obvious why Ron picked the Wand: His whole life he was the also-ran, the hanger-on, the weakest of the trio. The Wand would make him someone powerful.

But why did Hermione pick the cloak? Is it just because it's the last Hallow left? Or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: doesn't she say in the next few sentances? I don't have the text in front of me but I seeem to recall that conversation

Comment: "You're supposed to say the Cloak," Ron told Hermione, "but you wouldn't need to be invisible if you had the wand. An unbeatable wand, Hermione, come on!"

"We've already got an Invisibility Cloak," said Harry, "And it's helped us rather a lot, in case you hadn't noticed!" said Hermione. "Whereas the wand would be bound to attract troubleC"

Comment: Hermione hasn't got any dead relatives to mourn and she readily identifies the wand with simply attracting trouble. That leaves a choice of one

Comment: @Valorum That sounds like it could make a decent answer

Comment: @MrSpudtastic - Go for it.

Comment: Sure you don't want the rep yourself? After all, I'd basically just be copying your comments from here lol

Comment: @MrSpudtastic - As analysis goes, I'm not sure it meets my personal criteria of "deeper meaning" since it's pretty superficial. If you think you can turn it into a decent answer though, knock yourself out.

Comment: @Valorum I agree that it's superficial. I specifically want a deeper meaning than that, as I state in the question.

Comment: While Ron does spell out some of his reasoning, I'd also like to think he wants the wand because it might be the first wand that works properly for him.

Comment: @Ellesedil After "Chamber of Secrets" - but *before* the start of "Prisoner of Azkaban" - Ron gets a new wand, purchased with some of the Weasley family's winnings, to replace the one broken at the start of "Chamber of Secrets" (and "Lockhearted" at the end).  What indications do we have that this new wand did not work properly for him?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

## Hermione has always been an objective individual

I think her preferred Hallow was a symbol of the type of person she is. In some sense, both Harry and Ron gravitated towards the Hallows that addressed some deep personal issues of their own (Ron's insecurities and Harry's great losses). In comparison, Hermione was someone who preferred to make her decision based upon pure facts rather than her emotions and personal loss.

She would have had to look no further than the outcomes of the 3 brothers to decide which Hallow she would have preferred.

Comment: I beg to differ. This is not the action of an objective individual. An objective individual would want the stone ... to call up Nicholas Flamel to gain the secret of the philosopher's stone ... and tear the secret out of it and add together all the knowledge of all the wizards that ever existed ... and make true the words "the last enemy that shall be defeated is death"

Comment: And it comes with the added bonus of being invisible to Tweedledee Potter and Tweedledum Weasley so she can sit down and read for a bit.

Comment: Same reason mentioned led Hermione to choose this Hallow about which she knows it exists "in real life" (if you want to call the books like that)

Comment: I would add, not just pure facts but _practicality_. Hermione is a pragmatist. That and the added bonus that the cloak is non-violent.

Comment: @Joshua *"Do I not destroy my enemy when I make him my friend?"*.  Now, which of the 3 brothers does **that** best describe?  (I also recall no evidence that the spirits summoned by the Resurrection Stone would be in *any* way obligated to answer questions asked of them...  This would make it potentially useless for the purposes you suggest)

Comment: @Chronocidal: It's written on tombstones because it's a verse from Revelation. In the original context the preceding verse precludes that meaning.

Comment: @Joshua It's actually 1 Corinthians 15:26, not Revelations.  Including the preceding and subsequent lines (so, 1 Corinthians 15:25-27), it's *"For he must reign, till he hath put all enemies under his feet.  The last enemy that shall be destroyed is death. For he hath put all things under his feet. But when he saith all things are put under him, it is manifest that he is excepted, which did put all things under him."* (KJV) But, you were already taking the quote out of context, so I responded in kind, as "making true the words" would mean literally bringing about the end of the world.

Comment: You misread that. Hermione is just like Harry and Ron. The cloak addresses her personal issues as well. It would have offered refuge or even protection from the fear she learned in the magical world. She has been discriminated against ever since day one b/c of her birth, as a muggle,  b/c of her skill (Wingardium Leviosa, anyone?), b/c she was asked out by Victor Krum, to name the most prominent. With the cloak she can become invisible and avoid her hardship. She was answering out of the same motivations as the other two.

Comment: @Joshua 1 Corinthians 15:26 & James and Lily's gravestone; here I thought you where making a http://www.hpmor.com/ reference

Comment: @user1129682 If you have your own answer, write it up as an answer; it has no business being a comment.

Comment: @user1129682 It's possible she filled a bit more the role of the shy geek in that moment, but in general we see no indication that Hermione would want to hide or run away from any problem. She doesn't go head on into conflicts without thinking first like Harry (e.g. against little toady), but she does stand up to any perceived pressure just with a bit more planing. In that perspective the cloak fits her character better. Ron directly goes for the power needed for direct confrontations, Hermione, Miss Intelligence, for the tool to gather said intelligence for proper scheming.

Comment: @KRyan no cannon, no answer. "purely oppionion based" ...

Comment: @FrankHopkins :-) That's why I'm not making this an answer. I do believe (!) she would like to not be insulted and not be discriminated against. I may be absolutely wrong here, but that is how I like to think about her. It is about coping with everyday life, which is made arbitrarily hard on her, e.g. starting with stupid insults from Malfoy in HP1 up to persecution by the MOM in HP5 (and following). This has nothing to do with "running from problems".

Comment: @Joshua You confused "objective individual" with "member of Slytherin" ;P

Answer (score 97):

Hermione is correct, it is obvious from the tale which gift is best.

- The brother who got the wand was killed the night after he boasted of the powerful wand.
- The brother who got the stone soon killed himself.
- The brother who got the cloak lived a long life and died in peace.

  > And then he (the younges brother) greeted Death as an old friend, and went with him gladly, and, equals, they departed this life.

The question is why the other two, knowing this, would choose the other items.

Comment: Ron points out that you're *supposed* to want the wimpy item but that any wizard worth his salt would want the powerful wand.

Comment: @Valorum She just said in the previous sentence "it's a morality tale", she tends to believe the books, so it fits her character that she applies the lesson from the book/tale. Many wizards may prefer the wand, but every user of the wand was killed.

Comment: I feel this is a better answer

Comment: @Valorum: Which merely shows Hermione what Ron's morality compass at that point is pointing to...

Comment: @Valorum A wizard who was *actually* worth his salt wouldn't **need* the Elder Wand.  Think of Dumbledore inspecting the cave in HBP with wandless magic.  Then again: we shouldn't judge those who feel they need some enhancement to perform - even if, as Voldemort found out, it sometimes misfires.

Comment: @Chronocidal - If Voldemort had the Elder Wand, he would (presumably) have won his duel with Dumbledore

Comment: The 'why' is simple, they already have the cloak.  Why lust after something you already have?

Comment: They already have a cloak of *invisibility*. This is a **cloak of immortality**.

Comment: @Mazura It is the same item in the end, but you are right that they do not know this at this point.

Comment: Just because someone else becomes a drug addict when they win the lottery does not mean, everyone does. While the story indicates certain desires and what their potential problematic consequences are, it's not a rule book, more a guideline, it can make perfect sense to choose either of the three depending on what your goals are.

Answer (score 11):

The reason why Hermione chose the cloak is pure logic and logic alone, and the story of the three brothers only reinforces that which can be figured out purely by logic.

What's the stone good for? Nothing really. It can't really bring back the dead only their spirits who apparently grow tired of being summoned back to witness the living, and there is some real consideration about whether the ring truly summons the spirits of the dead to you, or whether they are an extension of your memory and desire to see them. (Similar to the mirror of Erised).

The wand, although an extraordinary tool to increase the power of your magic, has the unfortunate side affect of pitting you against any and all wizards that crave for more power. You will be forced to live the life of involuntary duels.

The cloak on the other hand is not coveted, its use is defensive in nature used for concealment, and to avoid or flee a fight. Chances are it's the one instrument of the three that will do the owner the most amount of good with the least amount of consequence or regret over that decision.

It makes the most sense logically that the cloak would be the most desirable hallow of the three, and Hermione being driven by logic rather than emotion or whim would not only chose the cloak but assume anyone else with one bit of logic or intelligence would also chose the cloak.

Comment: I would disagree *slightly* about the Wand:  Neither Gregorovich (who wanted to **study** the wand, but not use it), nor Dumbledore (who wielded significant **Political** power, and was well known as a magical prodigy *before* he acquired it) were brought conflict by the owning the wand - however, neither of them had cause to advertise ownership of the Elder Wand (and, arguably, both had good reason to conceal the fact!), while most of the negative consequences that previous holders experienced seem to stem from their egos and boasting about how "unbeatable" they were (or their wand was).

Comment: Both of your examples cite already powerful wizards, and as you stated they concealed the fact they owned them very carefully. This is evidenced that it took years for Voldemort to discover gregorivic had it when in fact it had already passed hands since he had it oh so long ago. Concealing the fact you have it is evidence that it causes problems for the wielder.

Comment: Not really...  *Advertising* that you have it causes problems, even if you **don't** have the wand.  In general, people are more likely to think "that person is a powerful spellcaster" than they are "that person must have the Elder Wand".  We see no evidence of Gregorovich or Dumbledore *actually* concealing that they owned the Elder Wand, just that they never went out of their way to mention it - very different.

Comment: Also worth noting...  Neither Harry, who shuns fame, and Hermione, who values her solitude, would be at risk from owning the wand.  Only Ron, with his desire to "step out of the shadow" of his family/friends would be in danger.  Of course, the flip-side to that is Harry (with the family he has lost) and Hermione (with the promise of lost knowledge) are both at risk from the Resurrection Stone, while Ron (valuing his living friends/family, and not being prone to much in the way of introspection or deep thought) is largely immune to the dangers it presents.

Comment: Really? With all the conversation that dumbeldore had with Harry about hallows and horcruxes? Somehow it was never mentioned that dumboedore in fact had at some point in time had possession of all three? Not even an oh by the way....No, he was concealing the fact even if not the physical wand.

Comment: *What* conversations about the Hallows?  Harry only became aware that they even existed **after** Dumbledore was dead.  When he later spoke to Dumbledore's portrait...  it discussed having possessed them.  (However, this has gone severely off-topic, considering I originally only commented on disagreeing with the sentence *"You will be forced to live the life of involuntary duels"*, by providing demonstration of 2 people who **didn't**)

Comment: My point is they didn’t because they concealed the fact they possessed the wand. That is evidenced by the fact that NO ONE knew, and it took a lot of digging and torture to find out gregorevic had it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98849/discussion-between-chronocidal-and-escoce).

Comment: That decision as outlined is not by pure logic. It's also by personal axioms. For instance, if you are a duellist anyway, a powerful wand that makes you more powerful and attracts more worthy opponents is a win-win! Far too many people confuse what comes logically to them based on their axiomatic preferences with "pure logic". Pure logic tells you nothing about what is a "better" choice. Because pure logic doesn't have any base axioms on what is "good" in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Because Hermione was always the one, who did not pursue power tools. She wanted to live peacefully, far away from all the danger.

The Invisibility Cloak, as the third brother, Ignotus Peverell, used it for, was to protect himself and his family and not a tool for power and violence.

Comment: "Because Hermione was always the one, who did not pursue power tools. She wanted to live peacefully, far away from all the danger."

This is what I was looking for. If you have proof from the books that this is true, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @TheAsh - seems odd that she'd be selected for Gryffindor then, when her brain power is more suited to Ravenclaw. What's the distinction between the two houses? Gryffindor is for the bold and brave. If Hermione's true nature is to be as far away from danger as possible, then the hat was wrong

Comment: @NKCampbell not a bad point.

Comment: Hermione is an academic. With the cloak (previously unbeknownst, *of immortality*, not just *invisibility*) she can read more books and learn more stuff, until she decides that she's tired of living. Wands and stones don't let you do that.

Comment: @TheAsh, In one of the books, she space-time-clones herself to learn more stuff at once... that's what she's about; not "power tools" +1, but how to *use* power tools, because the ultimate power in the universe is knowledge.

Comment: @NKCampbell The hat is never wrong. It is not really deciding but more discussing which house you go to. But yeah generally Hermione would be a better fit for Ravenclaw. She also liked to stand up for others rights which is brave making gryffindor a viable option.

Comment: is there any actual evidence the cloak bestows immortality @Mazura? Yes, the tale says it does, but Dumbledore doesn't buy the tale as literal.

Comment: @NKCampbell Indeed the only description regarding the cloak that we have is that it grants true invisibility, not (or at least not easily) undone by any spell and not wearing off. So like the wand, it seems to just be particularly good at what it does.

Comment: except even Moody's magical eye could apparently see through the cloak - so it's not even a perfect artifact :D @FrankHopkins

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where Hermione's heart and head are in perfect alignment.  I agree with @QuestionAuthority's answer and others that indicate that the Cloak is the logical choice when you look at the outcome of the brothers in the tale.  I also agree with @whelsas that Hermione didn't crave power.

I disagree with @Escoce that emotion had absolutely no place in Hermione's choice.  Hermione is ready to take risks when needed but when we see her at her most vulnerable, more than anything she wants to feel safe and secure.  As a child, she is desperate for her teachers' approval and good grades, but she never seems to be aiming for any special school awards; she just wants to be sure she is secure at Hogwarts and in the Wizarding world.  She (maybe in half-jest) calls being expelled a worse outcome than being killed, and her Boggart is failing her exams (and therefore having to leave the school and hence the magical world).

I think it's an emotional choice because the idea of being able to hide so well from her fears appeals to her more than having the power to take them on.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you could edit in some quotes and other evidence to support the points you are making.